# How to properly use opCall?

Tags: operator-overloading, d

```
struct Foo{

  int _a;

  this(int a){ _a = a; }

  int opCall(int b){ return b * b; }
}

Foo f;
int rt = f(33); //Error: cannot implicitly convert expression ((Foo __ctmp1294 = 0;
                //, __ctmp1294).this(33)) of type Foo to int
```

I can't find enough information on `opCall` in TDPL or the website.

I need both the `this()` and `opCall()`, but, when the `this()` is present, the above code doesn't work.  Do I have to get rid of the constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above code should work, but doesn't due to bug [#6036](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=6036).